# Output file pulling zero from input

Tags: c++

Alright, I've been lurking for a bit now, trying to read up and figure out my problem, but I'm stumped.

I am trying to pull data from bloodData, which is a dat file that has a bunch of integers formatted like so:

4122    90 78 50

3123    110 92 83 95 77

3183     123 94 97 99

However, when I run my extraction, all I get is 0. I'm assuming that I am reading my file wrong. Where's the flaw in my thinking? I'm only two weeks into learning C++.

```
    while(bloodData.good())                      //Need to write while !EOF (changed: while True)
    {
        bloodData >> patientID;                 //Get patient ID (stop at first whitespace)
        patientsBloodData << patientID;         //Output patients ID
        while(getchar() != '\n')                //Need to write while !\n to loop through the measurements given
        {
            bloodData >> bpMeasurement;         //Extract a BP measurement
            bpTotal = bpMeasurement + bpTotal; //Add bpMeasurement to bpTotal
            bpIncrement++;                     //Increment number of blood pressure measurements
        }

        bpAvg = float(bpTotal) / float(bpIncrement);                        //Calculate the blood pressure average
        patientsBloodData << setw(5) << bpIncrement << setw(5) << bpAvg;    //Output and format the # of measurements
                                                                            //and blood pressure average
    }
```

Comment: `getchar()` reads from standard input, but the data is coming from the bloodData stream.  That doesn't look right to me...

Comment: @jim lewis I was kind of wondering about that, if it was proper usage. Figured I might have to do some sort of getline() instead of getchar(), but implementation is still a bit tricky for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much better to read entire lines with `std::getline` and then also include the read from the stream inside the loop checks.

Here is an amended program to demonstrate:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using std::setw;

auto data{R"(4122 90 78 50
3123 110 92 83 95 77
3183 123 94 97 99)"};

int main()
{
    std::istringstream bloodData{data};
    auto& patientsBloodData = std::cout;

    //while(bloodData.good())                      //Need to write while !EOF (changed: while True)

    for(std::string line; std::getline(bloodData, line);)
    {
        int patientID{};
        int bpMeasurement{};
        int bpTotal{};
        int bpIncrement{};
        float bpAvg{};
        std::istringstream bloodData_row{line};
        bloodData_row >> patientID;                 //Get patient ID (stop at first whitespace)
        patientsBloodData << patientID;         //Output patients ID

        //while(getchar() != '\n')                //Need to write while !\n to loop through the measurements given
        while(bloodData_row >> bpMeasurement)
        {
            //bloodData >> bpMeasurement;         //Extract a BP measurement
            bpTotal = bpMeasurement + bpTotal; //Add bpMeasurement to bpTotal
            bpIncrement++;                     //Increment number of blood pressure measurements
        }

        bpAvg = float(bpTotal) / float(bpIncrement);                        //Calculate the blood pressure average
        patientsBloodData << setw(5) << bpIncrement << setw(10) << bpAvg << '\n';    //Output and format the # of measurements
                                                                            //and blood pressure average
    }
}
```

Output:

```
4122    3   72.6667
3123    5      91.4
3183    4    103.25
```

Comment: Still new tor this, so could you please explain the usage of {} at the end of your declarations? Ex: int patientID{};

Comment: @Truzen It is [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) and in this case will perform [zero initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization).

Comment: Huh, interesting. Thanks for the references. I'll dig more into them tomorrow on my lunch break.

Comment: The usage of istringstream was the main thing handing me back on this project. I figured that I needed to use getline(), but then trying to extract directly from it was giving me a headache; istringstream solved that. Granted, now the data is pulling a weird formatting line, but that's a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

To pull data from a data file you can simply (in your .cpp file):

```
while(cin >> patientID) {
}
```

After you compile your code, and get your executable, you can send the file bloodData.txt as direct stream to your code (in CLI):

```
./a.out < bloodData.txt
```

This will send all the contents of bloodData.txt into cin which will send the contents to the variable PatientID, until it reaches the EOF character which causes the bool to return false of the while statement.

Comment: Was the ; an accident in while(cin >> patientID); {

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that I had access to do that @Philip